# Cant scrape table from site

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the ranking table on this site: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores

But I cant get the data, for now i have this code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from logzero import logfile, logger


class ScrapeTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrape-table"
    allowed_domains = ["toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        # headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("headless")
        desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

        driver.get("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores")
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        for table in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"datatable-1")]//tr'):
            data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
            print(data)
```

Any insights on how to get the data from the table would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why you are using scrapy and selenium at the same time, but let's say just to use selenium. To get the text from the table, you can do something very easy like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

driver.get("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="datatable-1"]')

print(table.text)
```

now if you separate everything in the table, just use the `find_element_by_xxx` function and select other parts via xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should select elements not element, if you need to iterate trough results.
Change your code:

```
 for table in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"datatable-1")]//tr'):
```

to code:

```
for table in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id,"datatable-1")]//tr'):
```